# In swi-prolog; How to create dup(L1, L2), where the elements of L2 are duplicated elements of L1?

Tags: prolog

In swi-prolog; How to create dup(L1, L2), where the elements of L2 are duplicated elements of L1? In the following way: L1 = [x, y, z], L2 = [x, x, y, y, z, z].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to all of these list operations in Prolog is basically to think inductively. What would `dup([], X)` give? Probably X = []:

```
dup([], []).
```

That's your base case. Now think about your inductive case. How can I handle one element, knowing I have `dup/2` handling the rest?

```
dup([X|Rest], [X,X|DupRest]) :-
    dup(Rest, DupRest).
```

The duplication happens in the head and we wind up only needing the body to recur.

Comment: Works like a charm. And I actually (finally) get the reasoning behind it :) Thank you Daniel!

Comment: @cogsci Welcome to Prolog! Glad to hear I was able to help you. It does take a little practice to get into the recursive mindset, but once you have it, a lot of things suddenly become easier!